# Open a directory/folder from IntelliJ IDEA using Command Prompt

Tags: intellij-idea, command-prompt

I want to open this folder which is a GitHub repository clone(D:\Acc\Tutorials\Programming\course-angularjs) from IntelliJ IDEA, using the windows command prompt. I can open the folder using commands like `subl .` for Sublime text and `code .` for VS Code. But I couldn't find the command to open it from the IntelliJ IDEA.

```
D:\Acc\Tutorials\course-angularjs>subl .
```

I found from some other answers that there is a way from IntelliJ IDEA, which is, Tools->Create command line Launcher. But I couldn't find it in mine. I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA Community version 2019.2.

I also used `<Intelli IDEA>` in the command prompt without knowing what it would do. But it also didn't work.

So is there any direct command for IntelliJ IDEA to open a folder, from the Command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `idea .` to open the project from the current directory.

[To know more..](https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2017/02/27/start-intellij-idea-command-line/)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But I needed to set my System's Environment Variable for IntelliJ IDEA first.